# "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

asOfDt = {$toDate: "2023-09-27"}
timeStamp = {$dateFromString: {"dateString":"2023-09-15T16:26:22", "timezone": "US/Central" }}
doc = {"dataBaseName": "cos_db", "asOfDate": asOfDt, "audit": [ { "creationTs": "timeStamp","creationProgramName": "ManualMongo","creationUserIdCode": "P046158","revisionTs": "timeStamp","revisionProgramName": "ManualMongo","revisionUserIdentificationCode": "P046158"} ] };
db.coll.insertOne(doc);
db.coll.find();

The insertion doesn't happen says validation failed.

Comment: Looks like you have applied the schema (with validation) for your collection. Check your schema and your data to be inserted.

Comment: There is no validation but by default mongo takes as strict I believe.

Comment: The validation for revisionTs and creationTs is bsonType:timestamp. But the above error gets resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var asOfDt = ISODate("2023-09-27T00:00:00Z");
var ts = Math.floor(new Date("2023-09-15T16:26:22Z").getTime()/1000);
var doc = {dataBaseName: "cos_db", asOfDate: asOfDt, audit: { "creationTs": Timestamp(ts,0), "creationProgramName": "ManualMongo", "creationUserIdCode": "P046158", "revisionTs": Timestamp(ts,0), "revisionProgramName": "ManualMongo", "revisionUserIdentificationCode": "P046158"} };
db.coll.insertOne(doc);
db.coll.find()

This does remove validation error but the time which we want to insert for creationTs and revisionTs doesn't come as expected. As timestamp is not user friendly. The bson type we suggest is date. Any more suggestion is welcome.